# [RAILS APP]: Bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm new on Ror and I developp a rails App (ruby '2.3.4', Rails 5.1.6), with a webpack installation.
In my navbar, I don't succeed to make my dropdown button deploying to display my menu items.. And I don't find how to make it work..?
Thks for your help.. :-)
Here is my code:

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Find Golf Courses Accomodation</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>


  <%#= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> <!-- Uncomment if you import CSS in app/javascript/packs/application.js -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?keyXXXXXXXX&libraries=places"></script>

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css">

</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
  <%= render 'shared/message' %>

  <% if current_user %>
  <input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<%= current_user.id %>">
  <% end %>

  <!--container inside each page -->
  <%= yield %>


</body>
</html>
```

shared/_navbar.html.erb:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn-form btn-small">
        <%= link_to "Become a host", new_room_path, style: "color: white; text-decoration: none;" %>
      </button>
    </li>

    <% if (!user_signed_in?) %>
    <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
    <% else %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to notifications_path do %>
      <i class="fa fa-bell fa-2x icon-babu"></i>
      <span class="badge" id="navbar_num_of_unread"><%= current_user.unread if current_user.unread > 0 %></span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
      role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <%= image_tag avatar_url(current_user), class: "img-circle avatar-small" %>&nbsp;
      <%= current_user.fullname %> <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to "Dashboard", dashboard_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Manage Listing", rooms_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "List Your Space", new_room_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Your Reservations", your_reservations_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Your Trips", your_trips_path %></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

In my Gemfile, some of my gems:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.1.6'
gem 'redis', '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.9'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0'
....
```

application.scss:

```
// Graphical variables
@import "config/fonts";
@import "config/colors";
@import "config/bootstrap_variables";

// External libraries
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "toastr";
@import "fullcalendar";

// Your CSS partials
@import "layouts/index";
@import "components/index";
@import "pages/index";
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/slider
//= require toastr
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
//= require card
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require cable
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Post your `application.css` or `application.scss` here.

Comment: You can see it now ;-)

Comment: Ok, sorry, that was redundant actually as long as bootstrap is working in general. I think you are missing `bootstrap-sprockets` in your `application.js`

Comment: Well I already have bootstrap-sprockets in my application.js  :-(

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you need: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#dropdowns

> Wrap the dropdown's trigger and the dropdown menu within .dropdown, or
>   another element that declares position: relative;. Then add the menu's
>   HTML.

Looks like you need to wrap your dropdown button and dropdown list in a div with the class of dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late buy hopefully it will help someone.

I had the same problem solved it by adding `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';` to `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file.

Got it from [here](https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79). I encourage you to read it, I find it very useful and informative.